# Script Failed! : script.raspbmc.settings

Tags: raspbmc

I just upgraded to the latest Raspbmc nightly build (`xbmc-rbp-20130124`) and now, when I go to *Programs* > *Raspbmc Settings* I only get a small notification on the lower right hand corner of the screen:

> Script Failed! : script.raspbmc.settings

Somebody else previously had the same problem [on raspbmc forum](http://forum.stmlabs.com/showthread.php?tid=5829), yet:

1. I ensured `/home/pi/.upgrade` owner is pi
2. [my `~/.xbmc/temp/xbmc.log`](http://pastebin.com/6qeKjfz1) is different

Any leads?

Answer (score 3):

Since [the Raspbmc community proved to be so helpful](http://forum.stmlabs.com/showthread.php?tid=6336), here is how I tackled the issue.

#### Short version:

One solution is to browse the ["nightlies"](http://mirrors.arizona.edu/raspbmc/downloads/bin/xbmc/nightlies/) and downgrade to the previous nightly build.

#### Long, detailed version:

1. SSH into the Raspberry Pi
2. switch to the upgrade folder:
   `/home/pi/.upgrade`
3. get previous nightly build:
   `wget -c http://mirrors.arizona.edu/raspbmc/downloads/bin/xbmc/nightlies/xbmc-rbp-<older_version>.tar.gz` <sup>†</sup>
4. extract:
   `tar xzvf xbmc-rbp-<older_version>.tar.gz xbmc-rbp-<older_version>` <sup>†</sup>
5. destroy the `.xbmc-current` symlink
   `rm /home/pi/.xbmc-current`
6. point the `.xbmc-current` symlink to the new folder:
   `ln -s /home/pi/.upgrade/xbmc-rbp-<older_version>/xbmc-bcm /home/pi/.xbmc-current` <sup>†</sup>
7. grant full access to the `xbmc-bin` inside:
   `chmod 777 /home/pi/.xbmc-current/xbmc-bin/`
8. reboot and check in *Programs* > *Raspbmc Settings* that it worked.

If anyone has a better / more elegant solution, please share.

---

<sup>†</sup> `<older_version>` — `20130121` in this specific case e.g., `xbmc-rbp-20130121.tar.gz`.

Answer (score 0):

Click on programs, right click rasbmc settings and chose to configure.
From there select the nightly update you want to downgrade to.

Comment: That's exactly the _Settings_ that I couldn't access in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the instructions are out of date. When I

wget -c http://mirrors.arizona.edu/raspbmc/downloads/bin/xbmc/nightlies/xbmc-rbp-20130121.tar.gz

I get a "no route to host" error.